# Add a MenuItem to multiple Menus

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm currently working on a MenuBar for a library(for books) in JavaFX8. I would like to add a MenuItem to several menus. If I do that, the output is a warning saying that this MenuItem has already been added and in the Application the Book Menu is not shown.

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        //Layout: BorderPane
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        //Define what is where
        layout.setTop(addMenuBar());

        //make it visible
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 900, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Library");
        stage.show();
    }

    public MenuBar addMenuBar() {
        //create the menubar
        MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();

        //create the menus
        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
        Menu bookMenu = new Menu("Book");
        Menu manageMenu = new Menu("Manage");
        Menu sortMenu = new Menu("Sort");

        //create the menu items
        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
        MenuItem booksAlphabetical = new MenuItem("Books alphabetical");
        MenuItem encAlphabetical = new MenuItem("Encyclopedias alphabetical");
        MenuItem addBook = new MenuItem("Add book");
        MenuItem addCategory = new MenuItem("Add category");
        MenuItem addPublisher = new MenuItem("Add Publisher");
        MenuItem booksReview = new MenuItem("Books sorted by review"); 


        //make the menus ready


        //file menu
        fileMenu.getItems().add(exitItem);

        //bookMenu
        bookMenu.getItems().addAll(addBook, booksAlphabetical,
            encAlphabetical, booksReview); 
        //manageMenu
        manageMenu.getItems().addAll(addBook, addCategory, addPublisher);

        //sortMenu
        sortMenu.getItems().addAll(booksAlphabetical, encAlphabetical, booksReview);

        //add menus to the menubar
        menu.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, bookMenu, manageMenu, sortMenu);

        //return the menubar
        return menu;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply said, it happens because you put a node to the two different parents (see the `booksAlphabetical` used twice):

```
bookMenu.getItems().addAll(addBook, booksAlphabetical, encAlphabetical, booksReview); 
sortMenu.getItems().addAll(booksAlphabetical, encAlphabetical, booksReview);
```

It's not known where the MenuItems `booksAlphabetical, encAlphabetical, booksReview` should appear, so they will be added only to the last one `sortMenu`.

Why does it happen? The JavaFX API is built that each `Node` has a collection of properties, including a parent property, that is only and only one.

The solution is to create them for the second time to make them unique since you want to use them twice.

```
MenuItem booksAlphabeticalSort = new MenuItem("Books alphabetical");
MenuItem encAlphabeticalSort  = new MenuItem("Encyclopedias alphabetical");
MenuItem booksReviewSort = new MenuItem("Books sorted by review"); 

sortMenu.getItems().addAll(booksAlphabeticalSort, encAlphabeticalSort, booksReviewSort);
```